# Drupal CCK Field Level Visibility

Tags: drupal, cck

I am using the Drupal 6 module [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) to allow using a CCK defined type as a user profile which is working well.  The issue I have is that I want the first completion of the profile to trigger an action however the user may save the profile without completing it.  My thoughts on this is to have a checkbox by the save button which states 'My profile is complete' which the user will select once they are happy with it, and I have another module which creates a trigger by using the node_api hook and checking the type of the node, the action, and the value of this checkbox.

Once this trigger has been raised I don't want that checkbox to appear again however.  If I could set the visibility of the checkbox using PHP code that would work as I could write a short script to determine if the completed action has already happenede and if so hide the checkbox.  Is there a module that allows this?  I haven't been able to find one.

I have also looked at using the same node_api hook to manipulate the profile as it is being displayed however the node just seems to have the values for the fields and not a form object that can be manipulated as I would have expected.  IS there a way to programatically manipulate a CCK form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [hook form alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) is what you are after. This can perform alterations to a form before it is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach using the [Save & Edit](http://drupal.org/project/save_edit) module.  Set your CCK profile type as "unpublished" by default.  Allow users to save it and/or save AND publish it with this module.  On publish, use triggers and actions.

This approach is arguably more in keeping with the *Drupal way* - configuration over customization.